# Stop CMake from prepending `lib` to library names

Tags: cmake

Sadly, CMake follows the awkward "implicit lib" convention, which inevitably causes problems when library names don't actually follow the convention (e.g. zlib), or have 'lib' as an explicit part of their name.

For example, suppose I want to add libusb:

```
add_library(libusb ...)
```

On Windows this will correctly produce `libusb.lib`. On Unix it will produce the hilarious `liblibusb.a`. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? I know I can set the output name explicitly using [`OUTPUT_NAME`](http://devdocs.io/cmake~3.7/prop_tgt/output_name#prop_tgt:OUTPUT_NAME) but I'd have to use some funky generator expressions to preserve `libusb.lib` on Windows. I wonder if there is a better way?

(And no `add_library(usb ...` is not a solution; the library is called *libusb* not *usb*.)

Comment: You could also rename your library to "usb" and force Windows to add "lib" to it....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can modify it via [`CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX.html). So in your case just do after your `project()` command:

```
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
```

Or you can change it per target via the [`PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) target property.

Comment: Also `set_target_properties(libusb PROPERTIES PREFIX "")` to achieve this per target.

Comment: Why doesn't it work when set in a toolchain file? Why does it need to be set **after** the project() command?